# How to sort the field (in the template) depending on their weight?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I use thinking_sphinx for search, and i'm trying to get the output table in which fields are grouped according to weight(from set_property :field_weights)

This define_block

```
  define_index do
    indexes status, title, content, manager, note, start_date, end_date
    has created_at, updated_at, parent_id, organization_id

    has user_id, :as => :user_id, :type => :integer

    has '7', :as => :model_order, :type => :integer

    set_property :field_weights => {
      :title => 1,
      :start_date => 2,
      :user_id => 7
    }

    set_property :delta => true
  end
```

How to sort the field (in the template) depending on their weight?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the Q, but it seems that you are trying to read the configuration of the field_weights from the view... 
I don't know if thinking_sphinx has a method to do that, but what I would do is save that configuration elsewere and use it where you need it...

```
class YourModel
    FieldWeights = {
        :title => 1,
        :start_date => 2,
        :user_id => 7
    }
  # more code here....

  define_index do
    indexes status, title, content, manager, note, start_date, end_date
    has created_at, updated_at, parent_id, organization_id

    has user_id, :as => :user_id, :type => :integer

    has '7', :as => :model_order, :type => :integer

    set_property :field_weights => YourModel::FieldWeights

    set_property :delta => true
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can use YourModel::FieldWeights to display the fields in order of their weights, for example:

```
YourModel::FieldWeight.invert.sort
```